# Combining array elements in order to assign to a variable in C++

Tags: c++

I am kinda a newbie in C++ and I am a having hard time with a situation.

My task is to create a decimal to [2:9] number system conversion. I am dividing the input number to the base and then, taking the quotient as the divident and continuing the same process.

For example if the decimal number is 149 and that number is calculated on base 2, my output is like this:

Remainder 1

Remainder 0

Remainder 1

Remainder 0

Remainder 1

Remainder 0

Remainder 0

Remainder 1

The outputs are the elements of an array named remainder.

And then I have to merge these array elements in reverse order (1001010) to form the new base number as an integer. How can I do this? I am stuck at this point. The above output is just the part of my output. The number will be prompted from user and it is going to be calculated on bases from 2 to 9. So, array lenghts may change (I have the code for the digit calculation, I have no issues with that).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int merge(int a[]);

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
  int dNumber;
  int system[8];

  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
      system[i] = i + 2;      
  }  

      cout << "Please enter the decimal base number which you want to use in the conversion: " << endl;
      cin >> dNumber;      
      int permanent = dNumber; //to keep the input number intact as it changes through the loops (used in line 53)

   int ndigits[8]={1};    

   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   {   
   while(dNumber > pow(system[i], ndigits[i])) 
   {
      ndigits[i] ++; 
   }
   }

   int dNumberNew = dNumber;

   for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++){

   for (int i=0; i>=0; i++)   
   {

       int Remainder[i], quotient[i];
       Remainder[i] = dNumberNew % system[k];
       quotient[i] = dNumberNew / system[k]; // since the variables are integers, this line does not assign decimals and finds the quotient easily.
       cout << dNumberNew << " " << system[k] << "'e bolundu. " << "Sonuc " << quotient[i] << " Kalan " << Remainder[i] << " cikti." << endl;
       dNumberNew = quotient[i];    

       if (quotient[i] == 0)
       {
           break;
       }
   }
   cout << "(" << dNumber << ")" << "_(" << system[k] << ")" << "=" << endl;
   cout << "" << endl;
   dNumberNew = permanent;
   }
}
```

Comment: Let's break this problem into two pieces.  Do you know how to iterate over an array in reverse order?  Do you know how to take a number from the array and add it to the string that represents your final output?

Comment: Yes, I reversed the order of my array. Now only thing that is left to do is combining. Answer to the second question is, it seems that I do not know. I tried to assign every element to the elements of an char array but ended up with a null array.

Comment: I have just edited my question and added my code. With input taken from user, I have an 8 element array called Remainder. I want to reverse the order of this Remainder array and then convert it to a string.

Comment: Look at [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) and [std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string). (or simply iterate in reverse)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function you can use as DecimalToBinary converter, analyze the code yourself

```
string toBinary(unsigned long long* arr, unsigned long long size) {
    string answer;
    for (unsigned long long i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        string binaryNum = "";
        while (arr[i] >= 1) {
            binaryNum = static_cast<char>((arr[i] % 2) + '0') + binaryNum;
            arr[i] = arr[i] / 2;
        }
        answer += binaryNum + " ";
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help, I will analyze it right now.